# Shiny app not working when R & R packages gets updated

Tags: r, shiny

Please help.

I was able to run my shiny app when I had R version 3.5.1. The app was working fine. Now, as per the need of the server that we have , I needed to switch my local R version to 3.6.1 and had to reinstall all the packages.
Now, I am using bootsraplib library to get the app in Bootsrap4 version. But , now all those elements which were defined earlier in a conditional panel / they needed to be displayed under certain conditions , they are not getting displayed even when , in the server side the code that needs to run to get the condition to get those elements displayed gets executed correctly. but in UI side, those elements are not getting displayed now.

> sessionInfo()
> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.4           cowplot_1.0.0            bookdown_0.20.1          tinytex_0.24             shinysky_0.1.3           waiter_0.1.2
[7] rhandsontable_0.3.7      rio_0.5.16               shinyEffects_0.1.0       shinymaterial_1.1.0      plotly_4.9.2.1           expss_0.10.5
[13] scales_1.1.1             ggplot2_3.3.2            formattable_0.2.1        shinydashboard_0.7.1     dplyr_1.0.0              lubridate_1.7.9
[19] shinydashboardPlus_0.7.5 shinyWidgets_0.5.3       magrittr_1.5             shinyjs_1.1              shinyBS_0.61             devtools_2.3.0
[25] usethis_1.6.1            kableExtra_1.1.0         knitr_1.29               DT_0.14                  shiny_1.5.0.9001

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] matrixStats_0.56.0     fs_1.4.2               webshot_0.5.2          httr_1.4.2             rprojroot_1.3-2        tools_3.6.1            backports_1.1.8
[8] R6_2.4.1               lazyeval_0.2.2         colorspace_1.4-1       withr_2.2.0            tidyselect_1.1.0       prettyunits_1.1.1      processx_3.4.3
[15] curl_4.3               compiler_3.6.1         cli_2.0.2              rvest_0.3.5            htmlTable_2.0.1        xml2_1.3.2             desc_1.2.0
[22] checkmate_2.0.0        readr_1.3.1            callr_3.4.3            stringr_1.4.0          digest_0.6.25          foreign_0.8-71         rmarkdown_2.3
[29] pkgconfig_2.0.3        htmltools_0.5.0        sessioninfo_1.1.1      fastmap_1.0.1          readxl_1.3.1           htmlwidgets_1.5.1.9001 rlang_0.4.7
[36] rstudioapi_0.11        generics_0.0.2         jsonlite_1.7.0         crosstalk_1.1.0.1      zip_2.0.4              Rcpp_1.0.5             munsell_0.5.0
[43] fansi_0.4.1            lifecycle_0.2.0        stringi_1.4.6          yaml_2.2.1             RJSONIO_1.3-1.4        plyr_1.8.6             pkgbuild_1.1.0
[50] grid_3.6.1             promises_1.1.1         forcats_0.5.0          crayon_1.3.4           haven_2.3.1            hms_0.5.3              ps_1.3.3
[57] pillar_1.4.6           pkgload_1.1.0          glue_1.4.1             evaluate_0.14          data.table_1.12.8      remotes_2.2.0          vctrs_0.3.2
[64] httpuv_1.5.4           cellranger_1.1.0       testthat_2.3.2         gtable_0.3.0           purrr_0.3.4            tidyr_1.1.0            assertthat_0.2.1
[71] xfun_0.15              openxlsx_4.1.5         mime_0.9               xtable_1.8-4           later_1.1.0.1          viridisLite_0.3.0      tibble_3.0.3
[78] memoise_1.1.0          ellipsis_0.3.1

Answer (score 1):

What version of shiny you were using earlier?

Try this - `options(shiny.jquery.version = 1)`

Comment: shiny              * 1.4.0.9003 2020-05-07 [1] Github (rstudio/shiny@4b676ac)